# How do I filter based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my data I `df`

```
Id   Food
1    Apple
1    Banana
2    Banana
2    Cherry
3    Banana
4    DragonFruit
```

The other dataset `df2`

```
Id
2
4
```

The result will be

```
Id   Food
2    Banana
2    Cherry
4    DragonFruit
```

Here's my code

```
df2['one'] = 1
df = df.merge(df2, on='Id', how='left')
df = df[df['one'] == 1]
df= df.drop_duplicates()
df = df[['Id' , 'Food']]
```

It works, but I guess there's exist better method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with column `Id` from `df2`:

```
df = df[df['Id'].isin(df2['Id'])]
print (df)
   Id         Food
2   2       Banana
3   2       Cherry
5   4  DragonFruit
```

Comment: @NabihBawazir Could you comment on why it would not be a good idea  ?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution, you could continue to use `merge`, without the `left` argument (*i.e.* do an inner merge):

```
df.merge(df2, on='Id')

   Id         Food
0   2       Banana
1   2       Cherry
2   4  DragonFruit
```